# NodeJS child_process ansi in stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, minecraft, child-process

I want to get something like

```
[06:32:35] [Server thread/INFO]: [0;36;1m  |    [0;36;22m|__)   [0;32;22mLuckPerms [0;36;1mv4.3.73[m
[06:32:35] [Server thread/INFO]: [0;36;1m  |___ [0;36;22m|      [0;30;1mRunning on Bukkit - CraftBukkit[m
```

but I get

```
[06:05:02] [Server thread/INFO]:   |    |__)   LuckPerms v4.3.73
[06:05:02] [Server thread/INFO]:   |___ |      Running on Bukkit - CraftBukkit
```

When running minecraft server using child_process

```js
prcs.stdout.on("data", function(d) {
    console.log(d.toString());
});
```

Comment: What is the structure of `d`? Is is a string already? Are the parts separated by padded spaces or tabs? What are `d`'s recurrent parts? (Then you can probably sort this out with regular expressions and/or string methods like `split` and `indexOf`.)

Comment: `d` is <Buffer>

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how `d` is shaped, here is something that complies with your example, probably not exactly behaving as you need but you can always try and upgrade it (and at least it doesn't require any dependency):

```
const versionRegExp = /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/;
d.toString().split("\n").forEach((line) => {
  // no idea what the spaces are made of
  const exploded = line.trim().split(/[ \t]+/);
  // add paddings to the first two structures
  const first = exploded.shift().padEnd(5, ' ');
  const second = exploded.shift().padEnd(7, ' ');
  // work out the content
  // condition based on `second`, or should it be remainder.match(versionRegExp) ?
  const remainder = 0 === second.indexOf('|__)')
    ? `[0;30;1m${exploded.join(' ').replace(versionRegExp, '[0;36;1m$&')}[m`
    : `[0;32;22m${exploded.join(' ')}[m`
  ;
  // format line and display
  console.log(`[0;36;1m${first}[0;36;22m${second}${remainder}`);
});
```

Comment: NO! I need to output ANSI from child_process process stdout, child_process is a module for nodejs

Comment: This code is to give you an idea of how it could be done (although it's very broad since you didn't answer my questions in comments). Adapting it to your context (which I don't know much of, given your succinct post) is up to you.

Comment: How do you don't understand?
I mean, child_process STDOUT doesn't output ANSI

Comment: Your question was about adding ANSI escape sequences to a string. Quoting: _I want something like [ANSI-enhanced strings] but I get [standard strings]._ If you don't like the answer, rethink the question.